# python json.dumps and javascript fetch get response object as string

Tags: javascript, python, json

I have a dict like:

```py
a = {'status': 1, 'message': "Some message" , data: {'id': 1, 'comment': 'Some comment'}}
```

Now I am converting it to json like:

```py
b = json.dumps(b,cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
return b
```

Now I am fetching a api which gives this response like:

```js
fetch(url, {method: 'POST', body: some_data})
    .then(response => return response.json())
    .then(response => console.log(response))
```

It gives me something like:

```js
a = {'status': 1, 'message': "Some message" , data: '{'id': 1, 'comment': 'Some comment'}'}
```

Here `status` and `message` are converting fine but the value of data should be `object` but it is giving string ?

What is the issue here?